# how to make calculator's history feature? in javascript

Tags: javascript

i make my caluclator and if i calculate numbers, it will write the only answer in history but i want to write full operations.
i want to write something like that, if i write 5*2 and equal to 10. it must written is history like that: `5*2=10`.

https://jsfiddle.net/rwLyofbx/

this is my small code but you can see full code in JSfiddle

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#backspace").click(function() { 
        var barValue = $("#bar").val();
        $("#bar").val(barValue.substring(0,barValue.length - 1));
    });

    $("#equal").click(function() {
        z1 = $("#bar").val();
        $("#history").append(z1 + "<br>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, do something like on your equal function :

```
function equal() {
   $("#history").append($("#bar").val()+"=")
    var a3 = c(eval($("#bar").val()))
}
```

[Click Here for Full Code in JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwLyofbx/1/)

Its Working

Answer (score 0):

Okay, do something like:

1. On <kbd>Calculate</kbd> or whatever, bind a function that pushes the instructions to an array.
2. For <kbd>Previous</kbd> or <kbd>Next</kbd> history buttons, bind a function that retrieves the values from the array!

Comment: @VateX No one here are freelancers. If you see my answers, I mostly *improve* code for already existing code. I know how to implement this, but I will not write, unless I see a considerable effort from you! And whatever I have mentioned, doesn't need much to implement. Create an array, bind functions, update HTML!